# how to dynamically show/hide input fields in Formik forms using the Yup's validation When()method?

Tags: reactjs, forms, formik, yup, formik-material-ui

I am a beginner and trying to create a form in reactjs using Yup validation. I am trying to experiment with a very simple form that has firstName, lastName. And I am trying to only show lastName field when firstName is validated

using the useFormik hook

```
 const formik = useFormik({
        initialValues: {
            firstName: "",
            lastName: "",
            // email: ""
        }, 
        validationSchema: Yup.object({
            firstName : Yup.string().max(15,"Must be 15 chars or less").required("required"),
            lastName : Yup.string().when("firstName", {
                is:true,
                then: Yup.string().required("req")
            })
        }),
        onSubmit:(values) => {
            console.log(values)
        }
    })
```

Yup validation and on submit func

```
validationSchema: Yup.object({
            firstName : Yup.string().max(15,"Must be 15 chars or less").required("required"),
            lastName : Yup.string().when("firstName", {
                is:true,
                then: Yup.string().required("req")
            })
        }),
        onSubmit:(values) => {
            console.log(values)
        }
    })
```

My actual form

```
 <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}> 
        <div className="input-container">
            <input
                id="firstName"
                name="firstName"
                type="text"
                placeholder="firstName"
                onChange={formik.handleChange}
                value={formik.values.firstName}
            />
             {formik.errors.firstName ? <p>{formik.errors.firstName}</p> : null}
        </div>
        <div className="input-container">
            <input
                id="lastName"
                name="lastName"
                type="text"
                placeholder="lastName"
                onChange={formik.handleChange}
                value={formik.values.lastName}
            />
           
        </div>
       
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Not sure if should hide/show the lastName input field in the form, I have already declared it inside Formik initial values object.

Answer (score 2):

There are two things to deal with here:

1. It looks like you only want to require `lastName` when `firstName` has a value. If that assumption is correct, you can do something like this:

```js
...
Yup.object({
  firstName: Yup.string().max(15, "Must be 15 chars or less").required("required"),
  lastName: Yup.string().when("firstName", {
    is: (firstName) => !!firstName,
    then: Yup.string().required("req"),
  }),
)},
...
```

In the above example, `is: (firstName) => !!firstName` is checking if `firstName` has a value. If you wanted to require `lastName` only when `firstName` is *valid*, you could change that line to `is: (firstName) => firstName && firstName.length <= 15`

2. If you only want to show the last name input when first name is valid, this should work:

```
<form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
  ...
  {!formik.errors.firstName ? (
    <div className="input-container">...</div>
  ) : null}
  ...
</form>
```

You could also shorten it a bit but the above solution should work. Shortened version:

```
<form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
  ...
  {!formik.errors.firstName && (
    <div className="input-container">...</div>
  )}
  ...
</form>
```

Comment: Ok, I will work on that now, however to my understanding I thought that by using the when() method when validating, then it will show up immediately on its own. 
so I should use the conditional values here and add the HTML mark up conditionally as well. 
and I need to do that for each input field I have that requires validation from another field to appear first !?

Comment: Hey Benjamin, thank you so much for getting back to me in time. However I still have a minor issue here , I am trying to completely hide the lastName field. Now it only disappears after I create an error message with firstName or after the firstName value is validated.
what I need to do is to hide it completely off and be able to show it up only when firstName value was fulfilled.
the real life scenario I am trying to make depends on a radio button, if clicked then we show specific fields if another radio button was selected then we show the second set of fields , does that make sense ?

Comment: Latest question: 
I have done a few changes to my code, I think the main issues despite what I wrote above was in the Yup validation, form was getting submitted because the validation logic was flawed.
so far now I fixed it and I am able to submit the form but I am not sure It's working properly. as It's a bit clunky.

Comment: Latest question: 
I have done a few changes to my code, I think the main issues despite what I wrote above was in the Yup validation, form was getting submitted because the validation logic was flawed.
so far now I fixed it and I am able to submit the form but I am not sure It's working properly. as It's a bit clunky.
CodeSandbox:: https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-smoke-cigipk?file=/src/Signup.js
code is there even if it's not working on codesandbox !!

Comment: Hi Mohamad, it doesn't look like the code sandbox you linked is currently working. If you want to get some of the compilation errors fixed up, I can take another look.

Comment: I already solved and got it to work benjamin, thanks